# How to sign in GitLab via http request?

Tags: http, go, https

I want to sign in GitLab via https request. I have the personal access token, may be it can help.
Then I want to make a request with golang.

Comment: If you already have a token you don't need to sign in anymore. What do you really want to accomplish?

Comment: I want to "go get" every project from `/dashboard/projects`. First, I need to sign in, then get list of projects and execute "go get" for each.

Comment: Use the API to get the list of projects: https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/projects.html#list-user-projects

Comment: Thank you @Peter  but at first I need pass authentication. And got a lot of troubles with authentication_token bacause there are three of them when I try to sign in and I don't know which one to choose. However, I've found a bash script which can sign in via HTTP https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47948887/login-to-gitlab-using-curl

Comment: You said you already have a personal access token. Just stick it in the `private-token` header as explained here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/#personal-access-tokens. That's much simpler than messing with a session cookie.