# curl is downloading the html rather than the actual zip file from gitlab

Tags: linux, curl, gitlab

ever time i try and download my artifact from GitLab i seen to get the html in a file rather than the xip files it's self.

I have found loads of similar stuff on here but none of the solutions work.

i have tried -l, -O -o changed the oupt file using --ouptput filename.zip, and it always download an html file.

link...

https://gitlab.com/dafabe/example/-/jobs/artifacts/master/download?job=build

how do i change the command so it downloads the actual file?

full command :

```
curl  https://gitlab.com/dafabe/example/-/jobs/artifacts/master/download?job=build --output filename.zip
```

tried this with an access toke setup

```
curl 'https://gitlab.com/dafabe/example/-/jobs/artifacts/master/raw/build/hello?job=build&private_token=<private token here>'
```

I get this responce...

```
<html><body>You are being <a href="https://gitlab.com/users/sign_in">redirected</a>.</body></html>
```

most recent attempt and results...

> ubuntu-trusty-64:~/stuff$ curl -L -H "PRIVATE-TOKEN:> xxxxx"
>   https://gitlab.com/dafabe/example/-/jobs/artifacts/master/download?job=build
>   --output filename.zip   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
>                                    Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed 100    98  100    98    0     0    189      0 --:--:-- --:--:--
>   --:--:--   189   0     0    0 19509    0     0  23717      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  168k vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~/stuff$ ls filename.zip vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~/stuff$ file -b
>   filename.zip HTML document, UTF-8 Unicode text, with very long lines
>   vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~/stuff$

Comment: You need to log in to Gitlab with cURL. What you're downloading is the HTML of the login page. See the following answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47948887/login-to-gitlab-using-curl

Answer (score 2):

This could be an authentication problem as someone mentioned in the comments (and in that case you can for example pass your personal token in the header request).

If your project is public you should be able to download the archive without authentication. But you might still get a HTML response if you are being redirected. In that case you can pass the option `-L, --location` to curl:

```
curl -L https://gitlab.com/dafabe/example/-/jobs/artifacts/master/download?job=build --output filename.zip
```

You can find out in which scenario you are by inspecting the content of your donwloaded HTML page.

To login with a personal token (see [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/profile/personal_access_tokens.html#creating-a-personal-access-token) for help on how to create one, pick `api` for scope), enter:

```
curl -L -H "PRIVATE-TOKEN: XXXXXXXX" https://gitlab.com/dafabe/example/-/jobs/artifacts/master/download?job=build --output filename.zip
```

where `XXXXXXXX` should be replaced by the token you have generated.

Comment: also with the `-L` option?

Comment: when i do the -L option i get a massive html file displayed on screen

Comment: just ran the html in a browser, it's a login page

Comment: you see a login page because your artifacts is not available without authentication (it would be the case for a public project). So you need to authenticate (see my updated answer on how to create and use a private token with curl).

Comment: Thanks but i tried and it still downloads and html file, I replaced the x's with my private token which has full access :(

Comment: Is that HTML page still a login page?

Comment: If your token is valid that should definitely work. Not sure if this is a copy-paste error, but the syntax is `"PRIVATE-TOKEN: xxxxx"`, not `"PRIVATE-TOKEN:> xxxxx"`

Comment: just created a new token still same issue I am not using a '>', could i send you the token? it is just an example project to test out git lab nothing confidential in it.

Comment: If nothing is confidential you can try to make the project public and see if it works

Comment: yes it works now, but i will need to have it working privately for real projects. defo putting key in correctly

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to use the Gitlab API https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/job_artifacts.html#download-the-artifacts-archive

Using the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

ACCESS_TOKEN=$1
PROJECT_ID=$2
BRANCH=$3

PIPELINE_ID=$(curl -s --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $ACCESS_TOKEN"  "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/$PROJECT_ID/pipelines?ref=$BRANCH" | jq '.[0].id')
JOB_ID=$(curl -s --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $ACCESS_TOKEN" "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/$PROJECT_ID/pipelines/$PIPELINE_ID/jobs" | jq '.[] | select(.name=="build") | .id')

wget -U "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.17 (KHTML,like Gecko) Ubuntu/11.04 Chromium/11.0.654.0 Chrome/11.0.654.0 Safari/534.17" --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $ACCESS_TOKEN" "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/$PROJECT_ID/jobs/$JOB_ID/artifacts" -O artifacts.zip
```

This script takes 3 arguments

1. Your private access token
2. Your Project ID
3. The target Branch

Add returns the artifacts as `artifacts.zip` for the latest execution for the job `build`